# webview content breaks/distorted in titanium android when scrolling

Tags: android, html, webview, titanium

I am having this unexpected issue in my current project in TITANIUM.
I am using a webview for showing a local html file. It works perfect in iOS and in some android device as well. But in most of the HD android devices the html page or the contents of webview breaks while scrolling. Here is my code

```
var htmlTemplate = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(Ti.Filesystem.resourcesDirectory, 'extras',     'learnMore.html');
    var cssTemplate = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(Ti.Filesystem.resourcesDirectory, 'extras',    'learnMore.css');![enter image description here][1]
var html = htmlTemplate.read().text;
var css = cssTemplate.read().text;

html = html.replace("#css#", css);
//Animations Transformations
var small = Ti.UI.create2DMatrix({
    scale : 0.05
});
var big = Ti.UI.create2DMatrix({
    scale : 1.2
});
var normal = Ti.UI.create2DMatrix({
    scale : 1
});
//Animation Durations
var smallDuration = 350;
var bigDuration = 350;
var normalDuration = 250;
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({
    backgroundColor : 'transparent',
    //navBarHidden : true,
});
var windowView = Ti.UI.createView({
    top : OS_IOS ? 20 : 1,
    right : 1,
    bottom : OS_IOS ? 10 : 1,
    left : 1,
    backgroundColor : '#fff',
    borderRadius : 7,
});
var closeImage = Ti.UI.createImageView({
    zIndex : 1,
    top : 5,
    right : 1,
    width : 35,
    height : 35,
    image : "/images/icons/black_cross_icon.png"
});
closeImage.addEventListener('click', closeWindow);

var webView = Ti.UI.createWebView({
    width : '100%',
    height : Ti.UI.SIZE,
    backgroundColor : "transparent",
    top : 0,
    html : html,
    //overScrollMode : Titanium.UI.Android.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER,

});
windowView.add(webView);
win.add(windowView);
win.add(closeImage);
function closeWindow() {
    if (OS_ANDROID) {
        win.close();
        return;
    }
    win.animate({
        duration : 300,
        transform : big
    }, function() {
        win.animate({
            duration : smallDuration,
            transform : small
        }, function() {
            win.close();
            webView = null;
        });
    });
}

(function() {
    win.open();
    if (OS_ANDROID) {
        return;
    }
    win.transform = small;
    win.animate({
        duration : bigDuration,
        transform : big
    }, function() {
        win.animate({
            duration : normalDuration,
            transform : normal
        });
    });
})();

win.addEventListener('open', function(e) {
    Ti.API.error('********************* Learnmore OPEN ***********************');
    if (OS_ANDROID) {
        win.activity.actionBar.hide();
    }
});
```

https://www.dropbox.com/s/ade8wssi5ima3gr/10671472_702509996463626_2272456868867723707_n.jpg?dl=0

Answer (score 2):

Ok now i know this is not an ideal solution but if you are a titanium developer you have to deal with this kind situations in daily basis especially for our enemy-friend Android.
So as a work around what i have done is reloaded the html of webview second time after the webview is being loaded for first time.

```
var toggle = false;
webView.addEventListener('load', function(e) {
    if (toggle == false && OS_ANDROID) {
        this.html = html;
        toggle = true;
    }

});
```

this is beacuse in my html file i have set 
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0.9,user-scalable = no" />

But unfortunately it was not taken effect some time and thus while scrolling it shows some buggy UI.After the work around it seems the meta tag works.
Hope it helps some one who came across something like this.